# tikz for loop with 2 statements

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

what I am doing wrong here? Both the `\shade` lines are individually working, but seems like I cant put both of them together

```
\documentclass[10pt,xcolor=dvipsnames,xcolor=table]{beamer}
\usepackage[]{biblatex}
\usepackage[customcolors,shade]{hf-tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shadows,petri,decorations.markings,shapes}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}\frametitle{Hello}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \foreach \x in {0,...,4}
      \foreach \y in {0,...,2}
      \shade[ball color=Red] (\x,\y) circle(.2){};
      \shade[ball color=Blue] (\x+.5,\y+.5) circle(.2){};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Try adding curly braces arround the two lines with shade commands.

Comment: A simple `\foreach` needn't braces around the loop code; for instance, `\foreach \i in {1,2,3} \draw (0,0)--(1,\i);` will consider the loop code as terminated by the semicolon. However, it's better to be clearer and consistent by adding braces: `\foreach \i in {1,2,3} {\draw (0,0)--(1,\i);}`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `\foreach` command needs, in general, its "body" to be enclosed within braces:

```
\documentclass[10pt,xcolor=dvipsnames,xcolor=table]{beamer}
\usepackage[]{biblatex}
\usepackage[customcolors,shade]{hf-tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shadows,petri,decorations.markings,shapes}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}\frametitle{Hello}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \foreach \x in {0,...,4}{
        \foreach \y in {0,...,2}{
          \shade[ball color=Red] (\x,\y) circle(.2){};
          \shade[ball color=Blue] (\x+.5,\y+.5) circle(.2){};
        }
      }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

If you have just one command that you want to include in the body, you can omit the braces, but you may prefer to include them anyway for consistency—many people do.

For more details on the `\foreach` statement, see section 83, "Repeating Things: The Foreach Statement", of `pgfmanual.pdf`: http://texdoc.net/pkg/tikz. (The fourth example there is quite similar to your case.)

Comment: *if the body has more than one `;` terminated elements*

Comment: Yes @percusse ... you are right but I am used to place the body inside braces anyway... I think it is better practice.

Comment: @koleygr: I do the same, but regardless of which way you prefer to write the code, it's probably best not to say that the command "*needs*" its argument within braces, as that's not actually true.